# Base-10 lognormal PDF integrated over log10(x)

Tags: normalization, density-function, logarithm, lognormal-distribution

From what I understand, the lognormal probability density function in base-10 is mathematically defined thus:

$$
p(x; \mu, \sigma) = \frac{log_{10}(e)}{x \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(log_{10}(x) - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}
$$

As any PDF is bound to be, this function is normalised - that is, integrated over all $x$ (I integrate numerically, with $x$ distributed uniformly between the limits of integration) gives 1. In addition, this function, plotted against $x$, shows a unimodal distribution that is skewed/heavy-tailed.

Now, if my understanding is correct, a lognormal distribution is a distribution in which the random variable's logarithm is normally distributed. That is, if I plot the above equation with respect to $log_{10}(x)$, I get something that looks like a Gaussian.

Correct me if I am wrong, but what I am plotting is this:

$$
g(y=log_{10}(x); \mu, \sigma) = \frac{log_{10}(e)}{10^y \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(y - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}
$$

But if I integrate this function over all $y$ (I integrate numerically, with $y$ distributed uniformly between the limits of integration), I do not get 1 (due to the $log_{10}(e)/10^y$ factor). In other words, what I thought was an alternate representation of the same function, is not normalised.

So my question is, are the two forms of the same PDF *not* equivalent, as it seems to be in this case? If not, what is the reason? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Comment: Closely related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14483 (Intuitive explanation of density of a transformed variable) and http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4220 (PDF value exceeding 1 is OK).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A crucial term in the PDFs has been omitted: the measure $\mathrm{d}x$.**  Really we should think in terms of the *probability element*

$$p(x; \mu, \sigma)\ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\log_{10}(e)}{x\,\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(\log_{10}(x) - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}\ \mathrm{d}x,$$

whence, substituting $10^y=x$ (and equivalently $y=\log_{10}(x)$), we may rewrite the probability element in terms of $y$ as

$$\eqalign{
g(y; \mu, \sigma)\ \mathrm{d}y &= \frac{\log_{10}(e)}{10^y \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(y - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}\ \mathrm{d}(10^y) \\
&=\frac{\log_{10}(e)}{10^y \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(y - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}\ \log(10)10^y\ \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(y - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}\ \mathrm{d}y
}$$

(because $\log_{10}(e)\log(10) = 1$).

This is the standard normal PDF.  Normally, one begins at the end, substitutes for $y$, and works backwards to obtain the pdf for the lognormal distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! Now I understand the mathematical equivalence, but I don't understand why the two forms appear different when plotted. That is, when I plot $p(x; \mu, \sigma)$ against $log_{10}(x)$, and $g(y; \mu, \sigma)$ against $y$, they don't match. The latter peaks at the value of $\mu$, whereas the former peaks at some point $< \mu$. Could you please explain what I'm doing wrong here? (I thought this didn't warrant a separate question because it's very much relevant to the topic of equivalence.) Thanks!

Comment: Did you see my reply at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14483?  It explains why the shapes must vary when the transformation from $x$ to $y$ is nonlinear.

Comment: I had seen it, but I guess I was confused. But I do get it now. So, to correct myself, and to rephrase your answer at [stats.stackexchange.com/q/14483](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14483) - correct me if I'm wrong - the plot of $p(x; \mu, \sigma)$ versus $x$ and that of $g(y; \mu, \sigma)$ versus $y$ are equivalent. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The graph of $p$ and $g$ are indeed "equivalent" in the sense of using equal *areas* (rather than equal heights) to represent equal probabilities, whether expressed in terms of $x$ or in terms of $y$.