# Can the multivariate-t distribution have density greater than 1?

Tags: density-function, t-distribution

I'm working with a Python implementation of the Multivariate T distribution, and I've noticed when I evaluate the PDF at certain points, the likelihood returned is > 1. This is causing issues in other parts of my project.

The implementation looks right to me, I've read through it multiple times and compared to the PDF listed on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution).

I'm wondering if the multivariate t distribution can have density > 1 at any point? There are so many free parameters (dimension of the data, degrees of freedom, covariance matrix, etc) that its hard to get an intuitive idea if it is possible. I know the single variate t distribution does not ever have density > 1, so I'm assuming the same holds here. Looking for some confirmation here though..

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Even the multivariate T *in one dimension* can have arbitrarily high densities.  Indeed, *any* scale family of distributions will exhibit arbitrarily large densities: just make the scale small enough.  The densities are inversely proportional to the scale.

Comment: More specifically for th t-distribution: The density can get arbitrarily large for $x=\mu$ (and consequently also in more or less large neighbourhoods) if eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ are arbitrarily small. In the one-dimensional case, $\Sigma$ is just a single number, and you can easily convince yourself of my claim letting $\Sigma\searrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the response @whuber, intuitively I can convince myself of this based on the PDF function. However when I plug in to Geogebra, the behaviour is strange.. as I decrease the degrees of freedom parameter, density goes to 0. I narrowed down the issue and it seems that gamma((d+1)/2)/gamma(d/2) does not limit to 1 as d approaches 0 from the positive side. Do you think this is just a numerical quirk of their implementation, or is this something special about the gamma function? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: That limit is $0.$  As the df approaches zero, the Student t distribution flattens down into nonexistence: the limiting density at *all* values of $x$ is zero.

Comment: I see, but didn't you originally say that as the scale gets small enough (i.e. as the df gets small enough) the density gets arbitrarily large?

Comment: That's correct.  But the df parameter is not a scale parameter!  $\Sigma$ is the scale parameter.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49794/919 for an explanation of scale parameters.