# Step on proof for variance of Gaussian Distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, variance

i am reviewing how to prove the variance of a Gaussian, and I am stuck very early on, following the proof at [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Variance_of_Gaussian_Distribution/Proof_1) link:[[image: first two lines of variance proof]

On the second line, after this substitution, where did the $\sqrt2\sigma$ come from on the constant outside of the integral?

Comment: Hi: They are using the substitution $t = \frac{x - \mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma} $. So, when they calculate $dt$, it ends up being $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} dx$. So, thats why it ends up in the numerator on the second line.

Comment: The first line of my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/415436/919 answers this.  Some intuition is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49794/919.  Ultimately, this is purely a Calculus question.

Comment: @mlofton thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to help. Usually, I'm getting help !!!!!