# How to relate the distributions of these trigonometric functions of uniform variables?

Tags: self-study, random-variable

> $\theta_1,\theta_2$ are two independent random variables distributed uniformly in $[0,2π)$. Let $X=\cos\theta_1,Y=\cos\theta_2.$ Prove that $\frac{X+Y}{2}$ and $XY$ are equal in distribution,$\frac{X+Y}{2}{\buildrel d \over =}XY$.

I can calculate the cdf of $X,Y$, like [PDF of cosine of a uniform random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309400/pdf-of-cosine-of-a-uniform-random-variable), but it's difficult to prove the distribution equality: the distribution function is too hard to calculate.

Comment: Please share your thoughts. Add the `self-study` tag and read the tag [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We can avoid calculating distributions altogether.**

In the following I will use "$\sim$" to mean "has the same distribution as" while retaining "$=$" to mean strict equality of random variables, as usual.

The cosine is a periodic function with period $2\pi.$  A periodic function $f$ with period $\tau$ simply is one that satisfies $f(x+\tau)=f(x)$ for all $x.$  Equivalently, $f$ is a function of the numbers *modulo $\tau$,* meaning that before applying $f$ to any number $x,$ $x$ is replaced by its remainder after division by $\tau.$

Periodic functions of a uniform random variable $\Theta$ supported on $[0,\tau)$ generally enjoy some useful properties we might exploit to simplify our work.  These include

1. $f(\Theta+\omega) \sim f(\Theta)$ for fixed $\omega.$
2. $f(-\Theta) \sim f(\Theta).$
3. When $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$ are independent uniform random variables, $(1)$ implies $f(\Theta_1+\Theta_2) \sim f(\Theta_1)$ and then $(2)$ implies $f(\Theta_1-\Theta_2)\sim f(\Theta_1).$
4. Moreover, $\Theta_1\pm\Theta_2$ are independent *when computed modulo $\tau$* and therefore the $f(\Theta_1\pm \Theta_2)$ are independent mod $\tau,$ too.

I leave the (easy) demonstrations to you, since this is a self-study problem.

Specializing to $\tau=2\pi$ and $f=\cos,$ use these facts and the [rules of trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) to justify the following reasoning:

$$\eqalign {
XY &= \cos(\Theta_1)\cos(\Theta_2) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(\Theta_1-\Theta_2)+\cos(\Theta_1+\Theta_2)\right)\\
&\sim\frac{1}{2}(X+Y)
.}$$

Comment: Thank you, it helps a lot.