# PDF of cosine of a uniform random variable with additional shift

Tags: probability, data-transformation, density-function, uniform-distribution

I need to calculate the PDF of a random variable, which is quite similar to what was asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309400/pdf-of-cosine-of-a-uniform-random-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, I have to deal with a shifted cosine function. Thus, my random variable is defined as
$$Y:=cos(X+\omega)$$
where $X\sim \mathcal{U}[-\pi, \pi]$ and $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.
In this case, I cannot use the trick with the inversion of the cosine, which was used [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/309414) to calculate the PDF of $Y$. How can I approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you would draw a simple picture, as advocated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/138922/919, you would immediately have the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the same PDF as $\cos X$, because $\mod_{[-\pi,\pi]} (X+w)$ and $\mod_{[-\pi,\pi]}(X)$ has the *same* uniform distribution. So, the cosine transformation doesn't feel the difference between the two.

Consider a simpler example, and let $X=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $Y=\mod(X+10,4)$, and assume uniform distribution over $X$.
$$P(Y=0)=P(X=2)=1/4\\P(Y=1)=P(X=3)=1/4\\P(Y=2)=P(X=0)=1/4\\P(Y=3)=P(X=1)=1/4$$
$Y$ is again uniform. The constant *inside* cosine transform has the same effect. it just shifts probabilities, but since the source distribution is uniform it has no effect.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! The minimal example helped and I now have a feeling about why cos(X) and cos(X+w) follow the same distribution! However, I'm unfamiliar with the $\mod_{[-\pi,\pi]}$ notation. Can you provide a small explanation of what it exactly does or post a referral link? Thank you!

Comment: It's actually an intuitive but abuse of notation I used for this specific case. It means whenever you have a number outside this range, you'll find the corresponding real number within the range by adding or subtracting $2\pi$ (since cosine has this period). For example, $$\mod_{[-\pi,\pi]}(3\pi)=\pi, \mod_{[-\pi,\pi]}(-6)=-6+2\pi$$

Comment: Cool, that clarifies a lot! But shouldn't it be "adding or subtracting a multiple of $2 \pi$". I mean, if $\omega$ is huge, it is certainly not enough to only subtract $2 \pi$. Sorry for being overly exact here, just want to get everything right ;-)

Comment: no problem, of course, I meant adding or subtracting $2\pi$ as much as it’s necessary.