# Joint PDF change of variables

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, density-function, bivariate

I [now understand how to conduct a change of variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58532/can-i-derive-the-pdf-fc-from-a-spatial-function-defined-as-cx) for a marginal PDF.

Now, given two functions that define parameter's spatially: $C_A(x)$ and $C_B(x)$, is it possible to construct the Joint PDF, $f(C_A,C_B)$?

Note: if C_A and C_B are independent, I understand that $f(C_A,C_B)=f(C_A)f(C_B)$.

Comment: This is not really a different question: the solution for a univariate PDF works, *mutatis mutandis,* for multivariate PDFs, and conceptually it's no different: you have to account for the differential change in area and (according to multivariate calculus) that is done by introducing the determinant of the Jacobian.

Comment: @whuber : If the answer is trivial, as you suggest, could you please spell it out for me?

Comment: I did not say "trivial,": I said it's "no different."  See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant) for instance.