# Gamma and exponential distributions

Tags: r, distributions, generalized-linear-model, exponential-distribution

Could someone please clarify for me the support of the gamma distribution?

According to Wikipedia (and other sources), the gamma distribution is only supported for $x>0$. However, according to Wikipedia again, the exponential distribution is a special case of the gamma distribution with the parameter $k=1$, although the exponential distribution is supported for $x \ge 0$. Does this imply that if the parameter $k$ of the gamma distribution has a certain value, say 1, that its support extends from $x>0$ to $x\ge 0$?

I would be glad if anyone could clarify this for me.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Comment: What difference would it make to include $0$ in or exclude $0$ from the support, given that this has zero probability in any case?

Comment: It may be worthwhile noticing that the Wikipedia article on the Gamma distribution specifies a support (to wit, $(0,\infty)$) that *disagrees* with the definition of [support of a distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Support_of_a_distribution) elsewhere on Wikipedia: according to that definition, the support is always a closed set. I suspect the authors of the Gamma article just didn't want to keep specifying that certain functions, like the PDF, are not defined at $0$ for certain values of the shape parameter.

Comment: thank you very much for your helpful answer! However, I think it would make a difference if 0 is included in the support, as for x=0 the value for the PDF of the exponential distribution is lambda, and not 0.

Comment: What difference do you think this makes? After all, the PDF is a *density*.  Its value at any given $x$ means absolutely nothing by itself and acquires any meaning only in using it to measure *areas* under the curve.  Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-is-ok/4223#4223 for a more elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, the support of a distribution is defined to always be a closed set, so in the case of the gamma distribution, $[0,\infty)$. Even if the density function defined by some formula, for some parameter values, then is undefined, that is not a problem. The reason is that *density functions are not really functions*! Their values at any given point do not give meaning, they have meaning only through being integrated.

So, in one point of view, densities are *equivalence classes of functions*, two functions $f, g$ being equivalent if they give the same probabilities (that is, integrals) for all events $A$: $\int_A f(x)\; dx = \int_A g(x)\; dx$ for all events $A$. So the value you assign to the density function at zero do not matter (This is the [$L^1$ view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).)  See also [Can a probability distribution value exceeding 1 be OK?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok/4223#4223)  for discussion.

Another point of view (leading to the same conclusions) is that densities are *differential forms*, see [Intuitive explanation for density of transformed variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14483/intuitive-explanation-for-density-of-transformed-variable/14490#14490)