# Probability density function for a logarithmic spinner

Tags: r, self-study, density-function

I'm having trouble deriving the PDF for the following problem (from the book *Doing Bayesian analysis with R and BUGS*):

> Consider a spinner of the kind often found with board games, but with
>   a log10 scale from 1 to 100 (covering 0 to 360 deg). The spinner is fair, so any value is equally likely. What is the pdf at point $x$?

I know that the $x$ value at angle $t$ is given by

$$x = 100^\text{t/360}$$

Doing some transformation

$$x = \exp^{(t/360) \times \log(100)}$$

$$pdf(x) = pm(x)/dx$$

I also know

$$dt/dx = 360/(\log100 \times x)$$

### Question

> How to derive the answer below, using the information above?

#### Book answer

> $$pdf(x) = 1/(2 \times ln(10) \times x)$$

Thanks.

Comment: Don't think in terms of degrees: it's a relatively arbitrary way of measuring locations on the spinner, anyway. If you do not find that your question is answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14483/intuitive-explanation-for-density-of-transformed-variable/14490#14490, then please edit it to show us what additional help you need and we can re-open this thread.

Comment: I've edited the question showing my ideas - i'll read the related question, thanks!

Comment: Fernando, please add the `self-study` tag to the question.

Comment: Ok, new tag added.

Comment: @whuber - could you please remove the duplicated tag?

Comment: It still looks like a duplicate to me.  The part in your new edit is a question of arithmetic, which is not really on-topic here.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, but doesn't matter anymore it was very simple.