# What does it mean to transform a random variable into a different distribution?

Tags: distributions, self-study, random-variable

I am trying to understand transforming random variables into a different distribution.  I don't get how this works.  Let's say X is normally distributed.  We have some function Y = g(X) that transforms X into a variable that is distributed differently.

How would this happen? Unless we square X or something like that, each X would lead to a unique Y, with densities equal to whatever the density of X was.  I am not understanding how we could transform X into another distributed random variable, and one that is known.

I'm doing homework and it wants me to transform X to a uniform distribution.  Conceptually, I don't understand how this works.  Let's say X comes from norm(0, 1).  No matter what function g(X) is, I'd imagine Y = g(0) will occur more times than Y = g(5).  I'm not understanding what exactly needs to be transformed.  Are we trying to transform the density itself - like flatten the density function out?

Thanks!

Comment: [How to transform gaussian(normal) distribution to uniform distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343952/how-to-transform-gaussiannormal-distribution-to-uniform-distribution)

Comment: If $g(y)=3$ for all $y$'s, would you support that $Y=3$ is Normal?

Comment: I don't see how that tells me anything about Y

Comment: @user2974951 I see.  We can use the CDF of the random variable, which converts it to a new random variable that exists between 0 and 1.  And then somehow we can normalize it?

Comment: Wow that's crazy, I just simulated it in R and using CDF converts it to uniform - seems like it holds true for any distribution.

Comment: Your question assumes that *densities* are conserved under a transformation, but that's just not so.  The distinction between a probability and a probability density is fundamental.  This leads me to suspect that https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14483 answers your question.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I've found what I needed.