# Distribution of the Square Root of a Beta Prime Random Variable

Tags: distributions, random-variable, transform

> Given a Beta Prime distributed random variable $X \sim BP(a,b) $ with probability density $$\rho_X(x) = \frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\frac{x^{\alpha - 1}}{(1+x)^{a+b}}, x > 0$$ Consider the distribution of $$Y = K \sqrt{X}$$ where $K > 0$ is a constant.

Does the PDF of this distribution have a closed form? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a "closed form"?  Of what--the PDF, CDF, CF, CGF, MGF, something else?  If you accept that the distribution of $X$ has a closed form for the PDF or CDF, then perforce that of $Y$ does also: just do the substitution.  Conversely, if that of $Y$ has a closed form, the inverse substitution gives a closed form for $X.$

Comment: @whuber I edited my post now to make it more clear. What I'm looking for is just the what the PDF of $Y$ looks like and if it has a name.

Comment: Your question is answered in many threads, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14483.  Depending on the values of $a$ and $b$ it has many possible names; for instance, when $a=1/2$ its a scaled Student t distribution.  It is a particular instance of a [Generalized Beta of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_beta_distribution#Generalized_beta_of_the_second_kind_(GB2)).  It's a particular instance of a Pearson distribution.  *Etc.*