# What is the proper representation of the density of a transformed variable-- 3 examples with different plotting axes

Tags: data-transformation, density-function

I am having trouble understanding when PDFs of transformed variables need to be modified (i.e., take derivative) for proper plotting. I've looked at [Intuitive explanation for density of transformed variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14483/intuitive-explanation-for-density-of-transformed-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1) and several other resources. Here, I will give 3 examples of different x-axes, and I hope someone can help me understand which PDF is correct for each axis.

Given:

$\ln(X) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})\,$

And use R to generate plots, where `pdf1` is unadjusted and `pdf2` is transformed by the derivative of $ln(X)$ (i.e., $\frac{1}{X}$):

```
X = seq(0, 50, length.out = 400)
pdf1 = dnorm(log(X), mean=log(4), sd=1)
pdf2 = dnorm(log(X), mean=log(4), sd=1) * 1/X
```

**Example 1** using linear X units and axis, which is correct?

```
plot(x=X, y=pdf1, type="l", col="red", ylab="Density")
lines(x=X, y=pdf2, type="l", col="blue")
title(main="Example 1")
legend(40, 0.3, legend=c("pdf1", "pdf2"), col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1)
```

[image]

**Example 2** using linear X units with log axis, which is correct?

```
plot(x=X, y=pdf1, type="l", col="red", ylab="Density", log="x")
lines(x=X, y=pdf2, type="l", col="blue")
title(main="Example 2")
legend(0.2, 0.3, legend=c("pdf1", "pdf2"), col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1)
```

[image]

**Example 3** using log X units with linear axis, which is correct?

```
plot(x=log(X), y=pdf1, type="l", col="red", ylab="Density")
lines(x=log(X), y=pdf2, type="l", col="blue")
title(main="Example 3")
legend(-2, 0.3, legend=c("pdf1", "pdf2"), col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1)
```

[image]